# Hibernate vs SQL

Tags: sql, hibernate

I'm currently implementing a new functionality to a tool in an e-learning platform. I need to retrieve some columns from 3 different tables in the database. The particular tool is implemented with Hibernate technology where a class is mapped to a database table.

However, I need to use some information from different tables to build a single class.

- Can you Hibernate provide this sort of implementation?
- If not, will it be appropriate for me to use SQL in this situation?
- Is it a good practice to have 2 database technologies in one place?

Comment: Your question is not clear but Hibernate supports native sql http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate is made to do this, multiple tables either through relationships such as many-to-one, or multiple tables which represent different subtypes, etc.  You can use entity-name to map a single class to two different tables for different situations.  So the answer is yes.

As to doing Hibernate and hand-coding SQL in the same application, I think it's a very common practice, sometimes it's 200% easier to do than figure out the Hibernate mapping for a small detail.  I'm referring to something like JDBC, but as nowaq points out, you cna do this *in* Hibernate as well.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion even though I have still not found the exact solution to my problem.

Comment: Thanks.  I think if you post more detail on what you are trying to do, you will get a more precise answer.

Comment: I finally used addScarlar to combine all the returned columns together and then map them in a single table.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Hibernate can do this. Take a look at this post: [Mapping One Java Class to Two Database Tables with Hibernate](http://jpa.ezhibernate.com/Javacode/learn.jsp?tutorial=13mappingoneclasstotwodatabasetablesjpahibernate).

Maybe its not your case, but in general having two tables mapped to a single class may be a signal that you've got something wrong with your design. Make sure to take a second look.

Try not to mix too many frameworks and technologies in your app. You may end up with bunch of dependencies and very complex, unclean code.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion nowaq. The current design only consists of a single table mapped to single class :). For this implementation, I do not need to map these tables to a class but I need a method which could return me resultsets to work with. For example, SqlReader is a method which I used before.